# Selecting values from a 4d tensor with a 3d tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, spatial-data

I've recently run into this problem in pytorch when working with 4D tensors which should be indexed with 3D tensors.

Let's say we have this 4D tensor:

```
possible_values.size()
torch.Size([2, 5, 5, 4])
```

where:

```
dim 1 = batch
dim 2 = x_axis
dim 3 = y_axis
dim 4 = possible values of coordinate (x_i,y_j)
```

we then have a 3D "indexing" tensor, which should be used to select the values of dim 4, based on an x and y coordinate:

```
coordinates.size()
torch.Size([2, 5, 2])
```

where:

```
dim 1 = batch
dim 2 = sequences of (x,y) 
dim 3 = (x,y) coordinate
```

for example, `coordinates` would look like

```
[ [ [1,5] [3,3] [2,4] [1,3] [2,3] ]
  [ [1,5] [4,3] [2,1] [5,3] [5,3] ] ]
```

what we want to do is to select from a batch the possible values for the coordinates specified by `coordinates`. So from the first batch we want to select the `4` values at coordinates `[1, 5]`, `[3, 3]` and so on.

I have looked some at `index_select` and `gather`, but can't get my head around it currently (or make it do roughly what I want).

Thanks.

Comment: Your `coordinates` tensor does not have to be `shape[1]=5`, right? It **must** have `shape[0] == possible_values.shape[0]` and `shape[2] == 2`, right?

Comment: what is the expected `shape` of the output, in terms of the shapes of the inputs?

Comment: The expected output is `[2, 5, 4]` that is, for each `(x,y)` coordinate the possible values for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's start by removing the batch dimension:

```
possible_values[i,coordinates[i,:,0],coordinates[i,:,1],:]  # [output is of shape [5,4]
```

The above gives the correct values for a single batch element. Now we need a way to broadcast this operation for all values of i (i.e. across the batch dimension).

```
possible_values[:,coordinates[:,:,0],coordinates[:,:,1],:]  # [output is of shape [2,2,5,4]
```

This is mostly correct but it is "over-broadcasted" (i.e. it returns the desired indices for each batch element, for EVERY batch element".) We now need to index just the main diagonal elements across the first 2 dimensions such that we get the desired indices for each batch element, for EACH batch element:

```
batch_size = possible_values.shape[0]
batch_idx = torch.arange(batch_size)
possible_values[:,coordinates[:,:,0],coordinates[:,:,1],:][batch_size,batch_size,:,:]   # output is of shape [2,5,4]
```

This solution leaves something to be desired in that it doesn't extend to arbitrarily many dimensions without modification (i.e. if you added a z-axis, you'd have to add an additional `coordinates[:,:,2]` index to the block and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`torch.nn.functional.grid_sample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.functional.grid_sample.html).
You do need to slightly modify your inputs, but I expect it to work:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

possible_values = possible_values.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)  # make the "channel" dimension the second one
out = nnf.grid_sample(input=possible_values, grid=coordinates[..., None, :], mode='nearest')
```